# Uploading the image file to the server doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob, prepared-statement

I was trying to upload a BLOB with prepared statements to the MYSQL database, but I can't find the reason why it isn't working. Could somebody explain me the reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registrieren</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        require_once "db_connect.php";

        //Arbeit mit prepared Statements, da diese gegen SQL-Injections sicher sind im Gegensatz zum Escapen
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Bild (Bild_ID, Inhalt, Info) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ibs", $picID, $image, $info);
        // set parameters and execute
        $picID = NULL;
        $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['userPic']['name']);
        echo($image);
        $info = "just an example";
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "New records created successfully";
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    }
    ?>
</header>
<main>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="UserPicUpload" type="file" name="userPic" accept="image/*">
        <button id="send" type="submit" name="submit" >Bild Hochladen</button>
    </form>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an aside, why did you give your page (in the "action" of the form) a .asp extension when your appear to be using PHP script?

Comment: Anyway, we'll need a bit more info than "isn't working" before we can help you...error messages, behaviour reports, debugging info, that sort of thing.

Comment: @ADyson I changed action to empty and the rest of the database is working. Now I have an error code, saying :_"Warning: file_get_contents(Hintergrund.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/mysql/bildUebergeben.php on line 19"_ , which is the line: `$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['userPic']['name']);`

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes here...

1. When you bind your parameters, they aren't even defined - you define
   `image` and `picID` and `info` after you bind it.
2. The uploaded file's content is available using the `tmp_name` key.

Regarding the picID: Depending on the use case, you *may* set this to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your database. Since the type is an integer, I doubt that you actually want to set these numbers manually.

This would leave us with the following code:

```
    $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['userPic']['tmp_name']);
    $info = "just an example";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Bild (Inhalt, Info) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("bs", $image, $info);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records created successfully";
```

Another word: Name your stuff either German or English and use that globally, but don't mix up the languages. It's rather confusing to have the `Bild_ID` named `picID`.

Comment: Your first point makes no sense. You can bind first then set the value.

Comment: @maio290 It's still not working using your advise. The value of the blob isn't inside the database

Comment: @Dharman - you're right about that one, I had to look it up though, was surprised. 

CoreIce:  What does var_dump($image) output in your case?